# is it possible to use a column from a query, check its value and create a new column based on that value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I hope my title is not too confusing, I basically have a query that looks something like that:

```
Select tblA.Field1, convert(Varcharr(10),
    Select Min(f) from (
                      values (tblA.Date1),
                             (tblA.Date2),
                             (tblA.Date3) ) As Fields(f) ), 101) as MinDate
```

Let's say I get the following results:

```
 Field1          MinDate
 17              10/02/2016
 29              03/02/2018
```

now, if in that same query, I want to create a new column, say MinDate2, and update the MinDate in the above result set, can I do something like that, say if I want to take the MinDate and do something like: (basically I want to add this in my query above)

```
 , if MinDate = even year, then add 1 year, if MinDate is odd year then add 2 years
```

So that my results look like this:

```
Field1          MinDate        MinDate2
17              10/02/2016     10/02/2017
29              03/02/2018     03/02/2020
```

Is something like that doable?

The reason why I'm trying to do it this way is because I am pulling the Min date from over 80 different columns, so as is, the query is a monster and I would like to keep it as short as possible (as long as it does what I need it to do)

Comment: When you say create a new column are you saying just include in the results of your query or actually create a column in the table structure?  Clarification needed because you say add column and update value.

Comment: yeah @Brad, include it in the result with the MinDate2. My apologies

Comment: Are those `Date1`, etc, columns stored as valid date data types?

Comment: yes, those are actual dates, saved as "datetime' fieldtype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQL like this to reuse calculated expressions. A subquery would also work too, it's more of a preference call.

```
WITH INTERIM_RESULT AS
  ( SELECT YT.SomeField1 + YT.SomeField2 Your_Value
      FROM Your_Table YT
  )
  SELECT Your_Value + 5 AS New_Value
    FROM INTERIM_RESULT
```

In a subquery it'll look like this:

```
  SELECT Your_Value,
         Your_Value + 5 AS New_Value
    FROM (SELECT YT.SomeField1 = YT.SomeField2 AS Your_Value
            FROM Your_Table
         ) INTERIM_RESULT
```

For your example in the comments:

```
      SELECT Field1,
             Field2,
             Case When Field2 = 1 then 'Hey' 
                  Else 'Bye' 
              END as Field3
        FROM ( SELECT Field1,
                      Something AS Field2
                 FROM SOME_TABLE
             ) TMP
```

Comment: but how can i use the MinDate in a subquery, it's telling me that MinDate is "invalid column name' I hope you know what i mean, say this is a simpliefied example: Select Field1, SomeThing as Field2, Case When(Field2 = 1 then 'Hey' Else 'Bye' END) as Field3 <-- this is what I'm hoping to do

Comment: Check out the edit. This is more of just an annoying syntax constraint in SQL server. You can't use an expressions alias in the same select clause, you need a middle step in the form of a CTE (with clause) or subquery.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

An example to do this (not sure if your looking to do this from your top query or subset of data) and you dont appear to have actual table structures in your query so an example to do it and you can convert it to be in your code:

```
DECLARE @DateColumn AS DATETIME = GETDATE()

-- the %2 does a check and if 0 is returned it is even, otherwise null and the case statement does the dateadd for you 
SELECT @DateColumn, CASE WHEN YEAR(@DateColumn) % 2 = 0 THEN DATEADD(yy, 1, @DateColumn) ELSE DATEADD(yy, 2, @DateColumn) END
```

This takes the DateColumn year and if results of YourValue % 2 returns 1 means it ODD, otherwise Value is Even

Answer (score 0):

A CROSS APPLY could be handy here.

That way the minimum date can be re-used.

And a modulus `%` can be used to calculate the odd + 2 year & even + 1 year.

**Sample data:**

```
-- Temporary test table
create table #tblTest (Field1 int, Date1 date, Date2 date, Date3 date);

-- Sample data
insert into #tblTest (Field1, Date1, Date2, Date3) values
(17, '2016-02-20', '2016-02-10', '2016-02-15'),
(29, '2017-02-15', '2017-02-09', '2017-02-03');
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
 t.Field1,
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ca.MinDate, 101) as MinDate,
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(year, 1+YEAR(ca.MinDate)%2, ca.MinDate), 101) as MinDate2
FROM #tblTest t
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT MIN(v.dt) as MinDate
  FROM (VALUES
      (t.Date1), (t.Date2), (t.Date3)
   ) As v(dt)
) ca;
```

**Result:**

```
Field1  MinDate     MinDate2
17      02/10/2016  02/10/2017
29      02/03/2017  02/03/2019
```